# Can we deduce that $A=D$?

Tags: group-theory

**Theorem**. Let $A$ be a finitely generated abelian group. Let $B$ be the torsion subgroup of $A$.  We know that there is an isomorphism $f : B⊕A/B→A$. Assume that we know that $g : B⊕D/B→D$  is an isomorphism where $B$ is the torsion subgroup of $D$.

My **question** is: Can we deduce that $A=D$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $\mathbb Z^2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z_2$ both have torsion subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$ but are not isomorphic themselfs.